# Creating a delay() function using <thread> (C++)

Tags: c++, time

I'm trying to create a delay function in C++, using a "delay(int x)" form factor. Here is the program I am running currently:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef chrono::duration<int, ratio<1,1000> > ms; //defines a ms

void f(int x){
    ms xmillisecs (x);  // defines the duration xmillisecs (which is x milliseconds)
    this_thread::sleep_for(xmilisecs);  // delays for x milliseconds
}

void delay(int delaytime){
    thread mythread(f,delay time);  // starts the above thread (the one with x ms delay)
}

int main(){
    cout<<"I hope this works";
    delay(1000);
    cout<<"This happens one second later";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles without error messages, but terminal gives the following output, which is clearly not what a delay() function should do:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating
I hope this worksAbort trap: 6
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of `delay` to delay the *current* thread (which you could do by just not making a new one in the first place)? As it is, you never joined or detached the thread you created before its destructor was called. Also note you can just use `std::chrono::milliseconds`, or just say `1000ms` or `1s` in C++14.

Comment: I like the delay(int x) form factor - is there anyway to redefine delay() such that I don't have to change the contents of main?

Comment: Yes, do the sleep in the thread the caller is running on instead of a completely new one.

Comment: Like this?:

    void delay(int delaytime){
     ms xmilisecs (x);
     this_thread::sleep_for(xmilisecs);
    }    BTW, I am using this arcane OOP template formalism to help me read C++ documentation, which is all written so formally like this.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how forcing it to an `int` meaning milliseconds really helps anything. Now you've just forced the user to guess what units it uses, whereas `sleep_for` takes anything and that anything is clearly defined (`500ms`, `3.5s`, `2h`).

Comment: I'm trying to simulate the arduino device development environment, which has a C++ wrapper which has delay defined in this specific way. I am temporarily departing from this environment to learn C++ properly, and then shall return when I feel comfortable enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` function only causes the *calling* thread to sleep.

In your case, you are creating a second thread which sleeps while the thread running `main()` continues executing.

It should look more like this:

```
void delay(int delaytime)
{ 
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delaytime)); 
}
```